# Cronjob starts multiple processes

Tags: linux, cron, incrontab

Cronjob creates multiple processes for the same script. 
One using

> /usr/bin/php /path/to/php/script

And other using

> /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /path/to/php/script

These are 2 separate processes. Why does this happen?
I am running Ubuntu 14.10 server.

Comment: Is one process the parent of the other? (hint: use 'ps fax' to see the relation between processes)

Comment: yes, /bin/sh -c ... was the parent of the /usr/bin/php.... process.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the

```
    /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /path/to/php/script
```

Is likely the parent of:

```
    /usr/bin/php /path/to/php/script
```

Cron will execute /bin/sh -c of the command you have in your crontab.  /bin/sh will then spawn a child process of the actual command you want to run, in your case:

```
  /usr/bin/php /path/to/php/script
```

Comment: Yes, correct, /bin/sh -c was the parent of /usr/bin/php.. process. The processes were executing script, making changes to the system, but were not killed. Not sure why and how. Anyways I have specified the SHELL=/bin/bash in my crontab, and it seems to execute only a single process. Thanks for your explanation. I believe crontab uses /bin/sh as the default shell.